# How to get GeForce card playing nicely with RadeonHD card on 12.04 64bit

Tags: 12.04, drivers, nvidia, ati, 64-bit

I have a on board ATI card and a second nVidia card.  I really don't care about what drivers are being used, there will be no 3d gaming, just a dev machine with 3 monitors, 1 on board, 2 on nVidia

```
:/etc/X11$ lspci | grep VGA
01:05.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RS880 [Radeon HD 4200]
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation G72 [GeForce 7200 GS / 7300 SE] (rev a1)
```

Currently it's running libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-quantal and I have display on the internal ATI card.  I have absolutely nothing on the other two monitors.

The Xorg.conf is also empty.

I tried installing fglrx but lost the GUI and spent quite a few hours getting the GUI back.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You can't have 2 video cards from 2 manufacturers in Linux because the kernel requires a module to operate the video card that is specific to each manufacturer and you can only load one at a time.

You can alternate between the cards by switching the drivers but you can't use both at the same time.

Comment: I saw a post about being possible with 2 xserver sessions, but couldn't find more details on it.